# 9 patch image with multiple patches

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have read about 9 patch images [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) and know some basics about how they work. While I know *top* and *left* borders define the area which is repeated or stretched when needed but **but I got confused as soon as I saw a nine patch image from android's Seekbar widget.**

[image]

It has **two** borders on the left (multiple stretchable areas) and I want to know

How it will be stretched?

Comment: It means that it is preserving the actual height of the drawable and only stretching the transparent background.

Comment: Thanks @Rod_Algonquin. Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: it scales the top and the bottom while the middle stays unchanged - the scaling ratio is 1:1 (or more precisely 3:3 since there are 3 pixels on top and bottom)

Comment: @pskink content is allowed in purple colored area?

Comment: The content area is defined by the right and bottom markers. Left and top markers will define the stretchable areas. Which can be multiple.